# Add Caption to table

Tags: r, gt

I want to caption the table at the top/bottom of a table. Is there a `caption` `function` in the `gt` package?

```
 gt(head(mtcars)) %>%
        tab_header(title="", subtitle="Table 1: Mtcars with gt.") %>%
        tab_options(table.width=pct(90),
                        table.border.top.style=0,
                        row.padding=px(4)) %>%
            tab_style(style=cells_styles(
                          text_align='left',
                          text_color='grey'),
                  locations=cells_title(groups="subtitle"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the `caption` argument by installing the development version of the package from Github.

```
#devtools::install_github("rstudio/gt")
library(gt)

gt(head(mtcars), caption = 'This is table caption') %>%
  tab_header(title="A", subtitle="Table 1: Mtcars with gt.")
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the caption left aligned instead of centered?

Comment: I could not find an alignment option for `caption`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems strange and inconsistent (and annoying!) to not have an alignment option for caption. Especially since gtsummary uses "caption" instead of "title" for table titles.

I found this workaround in another thread ([Format caption of gtsummary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047679/format-caption-of-gtsummary-tables)). The idea is to enter the caption as html and do the formatting there.

```
"<div style='text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color: grey'> Table 1. Patient Characteristics</div>"
```