# Format caption of gtsummary tables

Tags: gtsummary

Hopefully this is not something very obvious I missed, but I am having a hard time finding how to format the caption of gtsummary tables.

I am trying to reproduce the table found here. I love the left aligned grey caption: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/tbl_summary.html#gtsummary-functions-to-format-table

[image]

I am using the following code, but the caption `Table 1. Patient Characteristics` is shown centered and in black ink, but in the example is left aligned and grey.

How can you format the caption of the gtsummary tables?

```
library(gtsummary)
trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, age, grade)

trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  add_n() %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Treatment Received**") %>%
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Median (IQR) or Frequency (%)"
  ) %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Patient Characteristics**") %>%
  bold_labels()
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, after posting, I found out that you can do it using css styles:
modify_caption("<div style='text-align: left;  font-weight: bold; color: grey'> Table 1. Patient Characteristics</div>"). Is this the "canonical" way to do it?

Comment: if you found a solution you can post it as the answer so it can help others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @mike's advice, I'll post my answer here, so it's easier to find for others.

As you can see in the code below, you can use a bit of css styling in
`modify_caption()`.

```
library(gtsummary)
trial2 <- trial %>% select(trt, age, grade)

trial2 %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_p(pvalue_fun = ~style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  add_n() %>%
  modify_header(label ~ "**Variable**") %>%
  modify_spanning_header(c("stat_1", "stat_2") ~ "**Treatment Received**") %>%
  modify_footnote(
    all_stat_cols() ~ "Median (IQR) or Frequency (%)"
  ) %>%
  modify_caption("**Table 1. Patient Characteristics**") %>%
  bold_labels() %>% 
  modify_caption("<div style='text-align: left; font-weight: bold; color: grey'> Table 1. Patient Characteristics</div>")
```

[image]